# Написание приставки "со", или "со-главный бой"

Tags: орфография, лексика, словообразование, заимствования, приставка

В последнее время вслед за английским написанием *co-main fight* в спортивной прессе повадились писать "со-главный бой". Правильно ли это?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, так как эта "**со**" не имеет никакого отношения к русской "**со**".

Выражение

> co-main fight.

Переводится как "основной бой".